# Onsubmit the div values show those values in json code format

Tags: javascript, json

i am new to json so i am trying to create json code on submit of the div values.
so here i have buttons called text section and image section

```
<div class="control-group">
    <button type="submit" name="text_section" id="text_section" value="Text Section" class="btn-info" onclick="toggler('show_textSection');" >Text Section</button>
    <button type="submit" name="image_section" id="image_section" value="Image Section" class="btn-info" onclick="toggler('show_imageSection');">Image Section</button>
</div>
```

So when i click on text section button i am showing below divs

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="tasktitel" class="control-label">Font Size <sup class="validfield"><span style="color:#F00;font-size:20px;">*</span></sup> </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="font_size" name="font_size" class="select2-me input-xlarge" data-rule-required="true">
            <option value="">Select FontSize</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>  <!-- Font Size-->
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="tasktitel" class="control-label">Font Weight<sup class="validfield"><span style="color:#F00;font-size:20px;">*</span></sup> </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="font_weight" name="font_weight" class="select2-me input-xlarge" data-rule-required="true">
            <option value="">Select FontWeight</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="200">200</option>
            <option value="300">300</option>
            <option value="400">400</option>
            <option value="500">500</option>
            <option value="600">600</option>
            <option value="700">700</option>
            <option value="800">800</option>
            <option value="900">900</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div> <!-- Font Weight-->
```

So when i choose those values i would like to create json like this

```
{
  "template": {
    "question_section": {
      "section_data":[
        {
          "index": 1,
          "section": "text section__2",
          "properties": {
            "font_size": "(respective value)",
            "font_weight": "(respective value)",
            "font_color": "(respective value)",
            "row": "(respective value)"
          }
        },
          
      ],
      "html_data":"<HTML_CODE>"
    },

  }
}
```

can anyone help me how can i manage this..thank in advance